# Left margin of a tex document

Tags: margins

I have used the instructions below to start a document.  I would like the left margin to be smaller than it is at the moment.  How do I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0.2cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-0.7cm}
\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If you indent your code by 4 spaces, it gets recognized as code and formatted as such. Also please make your code compilable and limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Comment: Appart from the comments above, you can just use the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package.

Comment: Hi and welcome, package `geometry` is great in setting the margins and other geometry related stuff. Doing it by hand will get you into trouble.

Comment: You might also want to replace your `linespread` with the [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package.

Comment: To make Johannes' comment more explicit, adding `\usepackage[left=5mm]{geometry}` to your preamble will set the left margin to 5mm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which shows how to pass roughly your existing settings to `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hoffset=2mm,textwidth=150mm,textheight=220mm,voffset=-7mm,left=10mm,verbose,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

`verbose` shows the results of your settings in the console output and log file. `showframe` shows the settings visually in your document:

[image: showframe]

Comment: He used `addtolength` so it is larger than the original value.

Comment: @JuriRobl Oops! Missed that completely. (Should not answer questions when so tired.) Thanks for pointing that out. I thought maybe it was meant to be 11/10 as it obviously wasn't meant to be that!

Comment: @JuriRobl Thanks for pointing that out - it looks better now, I think ;).